# How to Create 2-D session array in PHP

Tags: php, session-variables

I am creating restaurant project having dish details. I want to achieve add multiple dishes without saving in DATABASE using session.

My operation is not functioning properly. When I add new dish it overwrite the value of previous dish and increment the array by 1

```
    <?php

$DBhost = "localhost";
$DBuser = "root";
$DBPassword = "";
$database = "tandoor";

$CS = mysqli_connect($DBhost, $DBuser, $DBPassword, $database);


session_start();

?>
    <?php 
$id = 0;
   if(isset($_POST['qty']))
   {
       $_SESSION['qty'] = $_POST['qty'];
        $sessonID = $_SESSION['id']  =  $id;
   }

   if(isset($_SESSION['qty'])){
       $qty=$_SESSION['qty'];
   }


?>
<?php

$orderinfo['id'] = $sessonID;
$orderinfo['qty'] = $qty;
$_SESSION['orderinfo'][] = $orderinfo;
print_r($_SESSION['orderinfo']);

?>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['did']))
{
    $Did = $_GET['did'];
}
?>
<?php 
$title = "Order details";
?>
<?php
$selectBannerQuery = "select * from banner";
$selectBannerCmd = $CS->query($selectBannerQuery);
?>



<table class="order-table">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Item Name</th>
                                            <th>Price</th>
                                            <th>Quantity</th>
                                            <th>Total</th>
                                            <th>Operations</th>                                                
                                        </tr>
                                        <?php
                                        for($i = 0 ; $i< count($_SESSION['orderinfo']); $i++)

                                        {
                                        if (isset($Did))
                                        {
                                        $sessonID = $_SESSION['id']=  $Did;
                                        }
                                         else {
                                             $sessonID = $_SESSION['id'];

                                         }
                                            ?>
                                        <?php
                                           if (isset($sessonID))
                                           {
                                           $selectdishinfoQuery = "select D_id, DishName, price from dishes where D_id= $sessonID";
                                           $selectdishinfoCmd = $CS -> query($selectdishinfoQuery);                                                
                                            while ($selectdishinfo = mysqli_fetch_array($selectdishinfoCmd, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                                                $id = $selectdishinfo['D_id'];
                                                $dishName = $selectdishinfo['DishName'];
                                                $dishprice = $selectdishinfo['price'];

                                            ?>
                                        <?php 
                                               if(isset($qty))
                                               {
                                                   $total = $dishprice * $qty;
                                               }


                                            ?>

                                        <tr>

                                            <td><?php if(isset($dishName)){echo ($dishName);}?></td>
                                            <td><?php if(isset($dishprice)){echo ($dishprice);}?></td>
                                            <td><?php if(isset($qty)){echo ($qty);}?></td>
                                            <?php

                                            ?>
                                            <td><?php if(isset($total)){echo ($total);}?></td>
                                            <td><select name="qty" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                                                    <option value="0" <?php if(isset($qty)){  if ($qty == 0 ){echo 'selected';}}?>>0</option>
                                                    <option value="1" <?php if(isset($qty)){  if ($qty == 1 ){echo 'selected';}}?>>1</option>
                                                    <option  value="2" <?php if(isset($qty)){ if ($qty == 2 ){echo 'selected';}}?>>2</option>
                                                    <option value="3" <?php if(isset($qty)){  if ($qty == 3 ){echo 'selected';}}?>>3</option>
                                                    <option value="4" <?php if(isset($qty)){  if ($qty == 4 ){echo 'selected';}}?>>4</option>
                                                    <option value="5" <?php if(isset($qty)){  if ($qty == 5 ){echo 'selected';}}?>>5</option>
                                                    <option value="6" <?php if(isset($qty)){  if ($qty == 6 ){echo 'selected';}}?>>6</option>
                                                    <option value="7" <?php if(isset($qty)){  if ($qty == 7 ){echo 'selected';}}?>>7</option>
                                                    <option value="8" <?php if(isset($qty)){  if ($qty == 8 ){echo 'selected';}}?>>8</option>
                                                    <option value="9" <?php if(isset($qty)){  if ($qty == 9 ){echo 'selected';}}?>>9</option>
                                                    <option value="10" <?php if(isset($qty)){  if ($qty == 10 ){echo 'selected';}}?>>10</option>
                                                    <option value="11" <?php if(isset($qty)){  if ($qty == 11 ){echo 'selected';}}?>>11</option>
                                                    <option value="12" <?php if(isset($qty)){  if ($qty == 12 ){echo 'selected';}}?>>12</option>
                                                    <option value="13" <?php if(isset($qty)){  if  ($qty == 13 ){echo 'selected';}}?>>13</option>
                                                    <option value="14" <?php if(isset($qty)){  if ($qty == 14 ){echo 'selected';}}?>>14</option>
                                                    <option value="15" <?php if(isset($qty)){  if ($qty == 15 ){echo 'selected';}}?>>15</option>
                                                    <option value="16" <?php if(isset($qty)){  if ($qty == 16 ){echo 'selected';}}?>>16</option>
                                                    <option value="17" <?php if(isset($qty)){  if ($qty == 17 ){echo 'selected';}}?>>17</option>
                                                    <option value="18" <?php if(isset($qty)){  if ($qty == 18 ){echo 'selected';}}?>>18</option>
                                                    <option value="19" <?php if(isset($qty)){  if ($qty == 19 ){echo 'selected';}}?>>19</option>
                                                    <option value="20" <?php if(isset($qty)){  if ($qty == 20 ){echo 'selected';}}?>>20</option>                                                        
                                                </select>                                                
                                            </td>                                                
                                        </tr>
                                            <?php } 
                                        }}?>
                                    </table>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multidimensional array in php SESSION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652702/multidimensional-array-in-php-session)

Answer (score 1):

Session is basically a global array you can make it nested arrays in that,

You can create a session like $_SESSION("dishes"=>array())

And then on wards every time you get a new dish add it like $_SESSION["dishes"][] = $array_of_new_dish

Comment: can you explain it by correcting my code.. it would be much easier

Comment: When you do `print_r($_SESSION)` you would see `array("id"=>123,"qty"=>123)` Update that so that you can see something like `$_SESSION = array("dishes"=>array("0"=>array("id"=>123,"qty"=>123),"1"=>array("id"=>456,"qty"=>456)))`

Answer (score 0):

below code is for you logic related to update your session cart if you want to add current qty with previous that ll be done in this way other logic ll work with you work flow.

```
  if(isset($_POST['qty'])) 
{ 
$_SESSION['qty'] = !isset($_SESSION['qty'])?$_POST['qty']:$_SESSION['qty']+$_POST['qty']; 
$sessonID = $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
 } 
if(isset($_SESSION['qty']))
{ $qty=$_SESSION['qty']; }
```

Comment: i have start_session in configfile.

Comment: have you import that file in to your current file. or any other which call before.

Comment: yes i have imported the file correctly.. session is not the problem array loop is the main problem.

Comment: @HarshKumar i cant see that file in you code. please edit you code with latest version so anyone can help you.

Comment: if(isset($_POST['qty']))
   {
       $_SESSION['qty'] = $_POST['qty'];
        $sessonID = $_SESSION['id']  =  $id;
   }

   if(isset($_SESSION['qty'])){
       $qty=$_SESSION['qty'];
   }

Comment: @HarshKumar here is a code which is updating you value what you want to do ?? on this place

Comment: problem is yet not solved.
when i submit a new order instead of adding new row it alter every row in table of previous order/s.
well can you explain the logic in this line code
$_SESSION['qty'] = !isset($_SESSION['qty'])?$_POST['qty']:$_SESSION['qty']+$_POST['qty'];