# cannot store in multidimensional session array

Tags: php, arrays, session, multidimensional-array

If I save a string in $_SESSION['breadcrumb']['category'] it successfully saves the string , but if I try to save the same string in $_SESSION['breadcrumb']['category']['shiv'] it throws the following error

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'shiv' in
>   E:\wamp\www\sugumar\mysuite\ajaxjobsearch.php on line 13

this is working

```
 $_SESSION['breadcrumb']['category']="<a href={$sitepath}/jobs?removefromsearch&name=category&id={$id}>$value</a>" ;//works fine
```

this is not working..

```
$_SESSION['breadcrumb']['category']['shiv'] ="<a href={$sitepath}/jobs?removefromsearch&name=category&id={$id}>$value</a>" ; //error
```

I want to save $id instead of shiv

```
$_SESSION['breadcrumb']['category'][$id] ="<a href={$sitepath}/jobs?removefromsearch&name=category&id={$id}>$value</a>" ;
```

Comment: `$_SESSION['breadcrumb']['category']` is already a string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multidimensional array in php SESSION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652702/multidimensional-array-in-php-session)

Comment: `$_SESSION['breadcrumb']['category']` refers to an already-existing string. `$_SESSION['breadcrumb']['category']['shiv']` is *not* defined, hence the error. A `var_dump()` of both the variables should show the difference.

Comment: I don't think that duplicate link is fitting.  Please consider retracting it.

Comment: @CarlosAlexandre: How is that a duplicate of this question if I may ask?

Comment: Try add $_SESSION['breadcrumb']['category']=array(); before the iteration. But, like @u_mulder said, it's already a string. I just referenced other question that shows other example working.

Comment: I don't think he is actually defining that one, he is just using it as an example. The questions is, why he can go two dimensional without specifying `$_SESSION['breadcrumb']` as `array` first, while it doesn't work the same way with $_SESSION['breadcrumb']['category']? The answer to make it work obviously is to define it as an array first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your deep `category` value is first a string, when you then try to access it using `[anything]` it is trying to access an `offset` of that string.  Here is an example:

```
$_SESSION['breadcrumb']['category']='<a href={$sitepath}/jobs?removefromsearch&name=category&id={$id}>$value</a>';
echo $_SESSION['breadcrumb']['category'][0];
```

This will output `<` because that is the character at offset 0 (first character).

Truth is `shiv` isn't a legal offset, so php will bang out a warning, and then desperately try to do what you asked it to... it will convert `shiv` to `0` and replace the first character of `character`'s value `<` with the first character of `shiv`'s value `<` (no noticeable change)

---

When the offset is a valid number, you can use it to replace a character in the string:

```
$_SESSION['breadcrumb']['category']='<a href={$sitepath}/jobs?removefromsearch&name=category&id={$id}>$value</a>';//works fine
$_SESSION['breadcrumb']['category'][0]='!';
echo $_SESSION['breadcrumb']['category'];
```

Output: `!a href={$sitepath}/jobs?removefromsearch&name=category&id={$id}>$value</a>`

---

That should sufficiently explain the error.

As others have stated, this is just a matter of forcing a round peg into a square hole.  To correct the issue, just declare a key after `['category']` in your first posted line of code so that `category` is the key to a subarray.