# Using Php SESSIONS for product variations

Tags: php, session, e-commerce

I am trying to make a PHP e-commerce website using SESSIONS. Each product MAY have a product type (veg, beef, shrimp) and/ or different options for the size. How would I organize this in a session? I viewed [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652702/multidimensional-array-in-php-session) stack overflow question, however, how would it be possible for the customer to add product a with type b with size c to the cart and then add product a with type b with size d to the cart using that answer? Is there any other way to organize this into a session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have different types of product in your cart, you can do it same way as in question you linked but add type to product ID.

What I mean is to do it this way:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$id.'-'.$type] = [
  'type' => $type,
  'quantity' => 1,
  'size' => 'M',
  // etc...
]
```

This way each type will be unique.

Comment: If I do it this way, then I would need the product id, type, AND size in the session name. ex. $_SESSION['cart'][$id . $type . $size]

Comment: You can have size inside, you dont need unique product for different sizes, right? (edited in answer)

Comment: I do. Sorry, I will clarify that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could make an (multidimensional)array which contains products and product information and then *json* encode it and save it as a session which can then be decoded when needed in PHP.
E.G.

```
$products = array
(
  array("Beef",22,18),
  array("Lamb",15,13),
  array("Chicken",5,2),
);
```

and then

```
json_encode($products);
```

> Which will look like this 
>   `[["Beef",22,18],["Lamb",15,13],["Chicken",5,2]]`

And can be saved as a cookie or session and then when needed can be dedcoded as followed

```
$var = json_decode($_SESSION["basket"]);
```

You could also add more values into the session array itself

```
array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $product);
```