# Can you store multiple arrays values in session?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, session

I was planing to save the search inputs as arrays in session.

```
if ($this->input->post()) {
    $recent_search = array("Country" => $this->input->post('country'), 
                           "State" => $this->input->post('state'),
                           "Building" => $this->input->post('building'), 
                    );
```

I have saved the array in session as

```
$this->session->set_userdata('recentSearch',$recent_search);
```

The thing is after every form submission I'm taking in new array values. I want to store those input arrays into the session without erasing the old one. Is there any method that I could use?

Comment: possible duplication: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652702/multidimensional-array-in-php-session

Comment: Yes, you can, But it's not a good practice;It will slow down your webpages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use localstorage or cookies rather than sessions.

Example:

```
$search_cache = [
   'Country' => $this->input->post('country'),
   'State' => $this->input->post('state'),
   'Building' => $this->input->post('building')
];

setcookie( 'recentSearch', $search_cache , time() + 3600 , '/');
var_export($_COOKIE);
```

Comment: Yeah I understand now. Thanks for the help.